# Can we change the in-app subscription start date?

Tags: android, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I am using google in-app subscription I am able to test the using app store.

Now what I want to achieve is I want to start the subscription at a specific date.
For example, Today is 10th of the month and user subscribe and I want to start the subscription form the 15th of the month.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If the delay is always, for example, 5 days you can set a period of free trial > 3 days in the Google Play Console.

You can [defer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#Defer) the billing.

I don't think that you can postpone the subscription , because the subscription start at the user validation. However maybe you can display the subscription popup at a specific date, not sure that is compliant with good practice.

Hope it's help.